# MySQL NOW() Returns Only Year

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

MySQL docs about NOW() function...

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. The value is expressed in the current time zone.

Here's my query...

```
$sql = "

    INSERT INTO `users` ( `username`, `password`, `email`, `time` )
    VALUES ('{$username}', '" . sha1( $password ) . "', '{$email}', NOW() )

";
```

The problem is that in the database I don't have the full datetime, but only the year. Any solutions?

Comment: What type is your date field? Can you show an example value?

Comment: Mmmm, delicious SQL injection.

Comment: @Sdaz MacSkibbons, like I haven't validate input before... xD

Comment: @Pekka It's int(10) like it was when I used UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It's int(10) like it was when I used UNIX timestamp.

`NOW()` works for `DATETIME` fields only.

You need to either convert your field to `DATETIME` (the preferable method), or convert `NOW()` into a UNIX timestamp using [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this same trouble and was stumped for the longest time till I read this question. I used mysql's now() function to update a member's last login time.

MySQL's now() returns the date time as a string, like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` - somewhere along the line I stopped using this and started using `time() (UNIXTIME)` (makes it easier to work with) which returns a string of numbers, like `1352254528`. But you can't store a string of numbers like this in a datetime field, and likewise, you can't store `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in an `int(11)` field. The latter will result in only the year being stored.

In the end you should use:

`int(11)` if you're going to use PHP's `time()` function to store the time as a string of numbers
or
`DATETIME field` if you're going to use MySQL's `NOW()` function.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
strtotime(now())
```

And you should definitely use `timestamp` or `datetime` as a type for your column.